# Change popup window into template alert Kendo

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-ui, alert

Here I want to change alert window into template that using alert Kendo UI. But , I was using AJAX to do the alert before.

**Here the alert window:**
[image: Here the alert window]

I'm need a help to code it in AJAX

> AJAX PHP

```
//AJAX call for button
    $("#primaryTextButton").kendoButton();
    var button = $("#primaryTextButton").data("kendoButton");
    button.bind("click", function(e) {

    var test = $("#dropdown").val()

    $.ajax({
        url: "../DesignationProgramTemplate/getTemplate.php",
        type: "post",
            data: {'id':test,'progid':array},
                success: function () {
                // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)                 
                    alert('success'); //coding alert
                    //refresh
                    //location.reload("http://hq-global.winx.ehors.com:9280/ehors/HumanResource/EmployeeManagement/DesignationProgramTemplate/template.php");
                },
        /*  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }*/
        });
    });
```

Any opinion on this above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `kendo.dialogs`:

```js
//AJAX call for button
$("#primaryTextButton").kendoButton();
var button = $("#primaryTextButton").data("kendoButton");
button.bind("click", function(e) {

  var test = $("#dropdown").val()

  $.ajax({
    url: "../DesignationProgramTemplate/getTemplate.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {
      'id': test,
      'progid': array
    },
    success: function() {
      // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)                 
      kendo.alert('success'); //coding alert
      //refresh
      //location.reload("http://hq-global.winx.ehors.com:9280/ehors/HumanResource/EmployeeManagement/DesignationProgramTemplate/template.php");
    },
    /*  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }*/
  });
});
```

---

Sample:

```js
$("#alertBtn").on("click", function() {
  kendo.alert("This is a Kendo UI Alert message.");
});

$("#confirmBtn").on("click", function() {
  kendo.confirm("Are you sure that you want to proceed?").then(function() {
    kendo.alert("You chose the Ok action.");
  }, function() {
    kendo.alert("You chose to Cancel action.");
  });
});

$("#promptBtn").on("click", function() {
  kendo.prompt("Please, enter a arbitrary value:", "any value").then(function(data) {
    kendo.alert(kendo.format("The value that you entered is '{0}'", data));
  }, function() {
    kendo.alert("Cancel entering value.");
  })
});
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.uniform.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.uniform.mobile.min.css" />

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<button id="alertBtn" class="k-button">kendo.alert</button>
<button id="confirmBtn" class="k-button">kendo.confirm</button>
<button id="promptBtn" class="k-button">kendo.prompt</button>
```

Comment: Can I insert it into AJAX ?

Comment: @HelpMe by _insert it into AJAX_ I think you mean with AJAX? If so then yes, you can call `kendo.alert('Success')`

Comment: Can you show in my code? I'm a little bit confused, sorry I'm new to using Kendo

Comment: I'm using button submit so that after success send the data, it will appear the notification alert success which I'm using AJAX.

Comment: I have edited the answer, is it what you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Your solution help me, thanks a lot!